# CAKEPHP:How to compare common items between two arrays 

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How do I compare two arrays and list common items in a third array.  I want to print the third array.  Please help guys.  My results are coming in two lists.

```
<?php 

    $appsubjects = $this->ProgrammeChoice->
    ApplicantsDetail->ApplicantAlevelQualification->
    find('list',array('fields'=> array('subject_code'),
    'conditions'=>array('ApplicantAlevelQualification.applicants_detail_id'=>$app_id)));

     $progrequirements[] =
          $this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->
    find('all',array('fields'= >        array('programme_code','subject_code','programme_name','compulsory'),
    'conditions'=>
    array('subject_code'=>$s_code,'compulsory'=>'true')));

?>
```

So now i don't know how to get a 3rd list of items for which the `subject_code` is the same for *Array(1)* and *Array(2)*, where `compulsory` is true.

The essence of my program is that I want applicants to enter their subjects, applying for different degree programs.  Then for each degree there are subjects which are required(*Array(2)*), and some are compulsory.  So my program should be able to list all degree programmes that matches the subjects entered.  I hope you understand my question.  Please help i'm stuck.

Comment: Can you post some example arrays of what you have and what you expect to get? Sounds like a job for `array_intersect`.

Comment: $appsubjects = $this->ProgrammeChoice->ApplicantsDetail->ApplicantAlevelQualification->find('list',array('fields'=> array('subject_code'),
    'conditions'=>array('ApplicantAlevelQualification.applicants_detail_id'=>$app_id)));

Comment: $progrequirements[] = $this->ProgrammeChoice->Programme->ProgrammeRequirementsSubject->find('all',array('fields'=> array('programme_code','subject_code','programme_name','compulsory'),'conditions'=>array('subject_code'=>$s_code,'compulsory'=>'true')));

Comment: Please add it to your post not in the comments! And format the code so it's readable. Lastly, these are find calls not array results.

Comment: The first one is my first array,and the second is the 2nd one.Now i want a third array for which the subject_code is the same,and compulsory is true.

Comment: That block is nearly impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, I think you are doing it wrong. You make two database queries and after that you want find common items. How about doing it directly in query? :) is there some good reason not to?

edit: or make third query after user has submitted something. some ajax and voilá.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to go into why you may want to compare arrays or not. But indeed array manipulation skills could always come in handy.

CakePHP has the [Set Array Management](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html) class. What you may need for finding differences in arrays is the [Set::diff](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html#Set::diff) function. It "Computes the difference between a Set and an array, two Sets, or two arrays". The following example is from the CakePHP 2.0 Book:

```
    <?php
    $a = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'main'),
        1 => array('name' => 'about')
    );
    $b = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'main'),
        1 => array('name' => 'about'),
        2 => array('name' => 'contact')
    );
    
    $result = Set::diff($a, $b);
    /* $result now looks like:
        Array
        (
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => contact
                )
        )
    */
    $result = Set::diff($a, array());
    /* $result now looks like:
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => main
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => about
                )
        )
    */
    $result = Set::diff(array(), $b);
    /* $result now looks like:
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => main
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => about
                )
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => contact
                )
        )
    */
    
    $b = array(
        0 => array('name' => 'me'),
        1 => array('name' => 'about')
    );
    
    $result = Set::diff($a, $b);
    /* $result now looks like:
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => main
                )
        )
    */
?>
```

Set also has other powerful utilities that I suggest you check out.
I use it all the time, when custom data manipulation is needed out side of the DB layer.